# In programmer’s notepad while coding, justify content comes up as wrong code

Tags: css

When I was just beginning to start coding with flex box, I encountered a weird problem regarding justifying content from flexbox which was deemed as wrong code by programmer’s notepad.

[image: image showing error for the right code]

Comment: Please, you should be [using **Notepad++**](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) *at least*

Comment: If you want your code syntax checked you should be using a proper specific IDE (Integrated development environment) , not a drop-in catch all replacement.

Comment: The rules for parsing/coloring that style sheet don't include that property is all. It's newer-ish

Comment: Programmer's Notepad is basically a dead project. The last release was 4 years ago, the one before that 7 years ago.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is about modern application and referencing for a project which (according to it's github) has not been updated for over 6 years. The project is perceived as dead and so there is no solution for the question asked.

Comment: Please, you should be use [sublime text 3](https://www.sublimetext.com/3).

Comment: Thanks everyone. I was pretty much working on programmers notepad till date cuz I felt comfortable in it but since it’s not supporting updates, I’m shifting to notepad++. And it worked there!!!! So thanks again . 

Answer (score 0):

Justify-content is a flexbox related property. It was first accepted on Google Chrome 29, which released in august of 2013 [link](https://www.google.com/search?sxsrf=ALeKk02ZYUG08behb4IfRMFh94xI08HTng%3A1598538874919&ei=esRHX7fYN4ackwWM0LnoAQ&q=chrome%2029.0%20release%20date&oq=chrome%2029.0%20re&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAxgBMgUIIRCgATIFCCEQoAEyBQghEKABMgQIIRAVOgkIABCwAxAHEB46BwgAELADEB46CQgAELADEAUQHjoJCAAQsAMQCBAeOgYIABAWEB5Q2GRYn2dgjnJoAXAAeACAAUyIAcUBkgEBM5gBAKABAaoBB2d3cy13aXrAAQE&sclient=psy-ab).

The program you are using to write your CSS in, is a small project developed by Simon Steele, and was last forked on Jan 4th of 2017 [github](https://github.com/simonsteele/pn/commits?author=simonsteele)
The project started in 2002 [as derived from the first commit](https://github.com/simonsteele/pn/commits?after=618ea4ad538b26a8795b1cdaa684f08b72d31d09%201399&author=simonsteele).

And as we can learn from the [issues page](https://github.com/simonsteele/pn/issues?q=) of this project on GitHub, you're not the only one experiencing these problems.

My guess is that the project was abandoned in 2017 and the developer did not yet implement css highlighting related to flexbox. You might want to try out other flexbox related properties to see if these get accepted.

If they do not, there's your answer.
If they do, something else might be going on.

Long story short, you might want to look into other free IDE's if the absence of highlighting troubles you. There are many great options on the market, but you'll have to find one that fits your specific needs.

Comment: Thanks mate. Tried on notepad++ and it works now. All good. Thanks for information.